# Limitar el numero de paginas de un paginador con PHP

Tags: php, php7, php5

Se tienen 5000 datos para mostrarlos en paginas de 100 en 100, haciendo un total de 50 paginas, el problema es que al mostrar la sección de paginas aparecen todas y lo que se busca es limitar esa cantidad y que solo aparezcan unas cuantas de la siguiente forma:

```
anterior 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 ... siguiente

anterior ... 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 ... siguiente
```

El código que se tiene hasta ahora es el siguiente:

```
function pag_test($ini, $limit_end, $total){

    $url = basename($_SERVER ["PHP_SELF"]);

    if (isset($_REQUEST['busqueda'])) {
        $busqueda = strtolower($_REQUEST['busqueda']);
        $busq = '&busqueda='.$busqueda;

      } else {
        $busq = "";
      }

echo '<nav aria-label="Page navigation example">';
echo '<ul class="pagination">';

/****************************************/
if(($ini - 1) == 0){
    echo "<li class='page-item disabled'><a class='page-link' href='#'><i class='fa fa-angle-double-left'></i>  Anterior</a></li>";
}
else{
    echo "<li class='page-item'><a class='page-link' href='$url?p=".($ini-1).$busq."'><b><i class='fa fa-angle-double-left'></i>  Anterior</b></a></li>";
}
/****************************************/
for($k=1; $k <= $total; $k++){
    if($ini == $k){
        echo "<li class='page-item active'><a class='page-link' href='$url?p=$k.$busq'>".$k."</a></li>";
    }
    else{
        echo "<li class='page-item'><a class='page-link' href='$url?p=$k.$busq'>".$k."</a></li>";
    }
}
/****************************************/
if($ini == $total){
    echo "<li class='page-item disabled'><a class='page-link' href='#'>Siguiente <i class='fa fa-angle-double-right'></i> </a></li>";
}else{
    echo "<li class='page-item'><a class='page-link' href='$url?p=".($ini+1).$busq."'><b>Siguiente <i class='fa fa-angle-double-right'></i></b></a></li>";
}
/*******************END*******************/
echo "</ul>";
// echo "</div>";
echo '</nav>';
}
```

Con la ayuda recibida he logrado implementar el for de la siguiente manera, con un if evaluo si hay menos de 10 pag.

```
      /****************************************/
    // SI HAY MENOS DE 10 PAG
    if ($total<10) {
      for($k=1; $k <= $total; $k++)
      {
        if($ini == $k){
            echo "<li class='page-item active'><a class='page-link' href='$url?p=$k.$busq'>".$k."</a></li>";
        }
        else{
            echo "<li class='page-item'><a class='page-link' href='$url?p=$k.$busq'>".$k."</a></li>";
        }
    }
    }
// SI HAY MAS DE 10 PAG
 else {
      for($k=max(1, min($ini-5,$total-10));
      $k < max(11, min($ini+5,$total+1));
      $k++)
      {
    if($ini == $k){
        echo "<li class='page-item active'><a class='page-link' href='$url?p=$k.$busq'>".$k."</a></li>";
    }
    else{
        echo "<li class='page-item'><a class='page-link' href='$url?p=$k.$busq'>".$k."</a></li>";
    }
    }


    }
    /****************************************/
```

Así esta funcional aunque lo veo algo largo, si creen que se puede acortar el código escucho sugerencias.

Comment: Hola, la verdad no veo complicado el problema, solo hace falta modificar el ´for´  y saber cuantos números quieres que aparezcan en el paginador, incluso te puedo dar una solución simple.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lo que necesitas debes colocarlo en esta parte del código:

```
/****************************************/
for($k=1; $k <= $total; $k++){
    if($ini == $k){
        echo "<li class='page-item active'><a class='page-link' href='$url?p=$k.$busq'>".$k."</a></li>";
    }
    else{
        echo "<li class='page-item'><a class='page-link' href='$url?p=$k.$busq'>".$k."</a></li>";
    }
}
/****************************************/
```

Como ya tienes calculado el total de paginas en `$total`, solo hace falta hacer unos pequeños cálculos dependiendo de cuantos números quieres que aparezcan, por ejemplo si quieres que aparezcan 7 números sería algo así:

```
anterior 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 siguiente
anterior 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 siguiente
```

Para esto debes modificar los limites dentro del `for` de la siguiente forma:

```
for($k=max(1, min($ini-3,$total-7)); $k < max(8, min($ini+4,$total+1)); $k++){
```

En resumen lo que hace la primera formula es evitar que la serie comience en números negativos o en pocas paginas antes de la ultima, la segunda evita que se sobrepase el total o los 7 dígitos de la serie. Al final el código queda de la siguiente forma:

```
/****************************************/
for($k=max(1, min($ini-3,$total-7)); $k < max(8, min($ini+4,$total+1)); $k++){
    if($ini == $k){
        echo "<li class='page-item active'><a class='page-link' href='$url?p=$k.$busq'>".$k."</a></li>";
    }
    else{
        echo "<li class='page-item'><a class='page-link' href='$url?p=$k.$busq'>".$k."</a></li>";
    }
}
/****************************************/
```

Espero te sea de ayuda, Saludos.

Comment: Lo he implemantado de manera algo torpe pero esta funcional, crees que pueda hacerse mejor, lo dejo en mi consulta a ver si me ayudas a maquillarlo

Comment: @JoseMHerreraV entiendo, buscas comprimir el código para el caso en el que el número de paginas es menor al del limite, para esto solo vasta con cambiar la parte de tu código que dice `$k < max(11, min($ini+5,$total+1));` por `$k < max(min(11,$total+1), min($ini+5,$total+1));` y así ya no necesitas el **if**. Saludos.